# What is ferrite foil used for?

Tags: ferrite

There is "ferrite foil" available on the market, often with self-adhesive layer on one side.

What are typical use cases for this foil? How and where it is applied? I was surprised not to find anything clear in the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It can be used to prevent a magnetic field wholly penetrating a sensitive PCB area. Thus induction effects are reduced and interference to sensitive electronics avoided.
- For the same reasons it can be used to avoid unnecessary attenuation of a magnetic field caused by unwanted eddy currents in metal structures.
- It can be used to "focus" a magnetic field in order to improve the coupling between a transmit coil and a receive coil (as in magnetic power transfer applications). Many power coupling applications can make use of ferrite sheet here.
- Because it's easily cut with scissors and shaped accordingly, it can be done pretty much on-the-fly when trying to improve power coupling designs. Lumps of hard ferrite may ultimately be preferred but trying to fix problems with malleable sheet is good for design development.

Comment: So I could put it over another side of my large LED indicators!!! They are 10x8 cm and I was always in a trouble that a hole of this size would negate any shielding from the enclosure.

Comment: They won't be so good at cutting out lower frequency electric field interference. Given that electric field interference is probably more likely (generalism alert!) maybe you should think about using a conducting shield instead.